# Serverside datatable combining column data and data from other tables

Tags: datatables, server-side

I had this datatable with AJAX:

[image]

And I wanna turn it into serverside since it will hold more than 10k entries. This is the code I made using Datatables documentation:

Server side get data:

```
<?php
 
/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simple to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */
 
// DB table to use
$table = 'library_book';
 
// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'title', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'subtitle',   'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'isbn',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'subject_id',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'author_id',     'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'creator_id',     'dt' => 5 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'creationdate',
        'dt'        => 6,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    )
);
 
// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'mycbs',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);
 
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */
 
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

SSP Class:

```
<?php

/*
 * Helper functions for building a DataTables server-side processing SQL query
 *
 * The static functions in this class are just helper functions to help build
 * the SQL used in the DataTables demo server-side processing scripts. These
 * functions obviously do not represent all that can be done with server-side
 * processing, they are intentionally simple to show how it works. More complex
 * server-side processing operations will likely require a custom script.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */


class SSP {
    /**
     * Create the data output array for the DataTables rows
     *
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $data    Data from the SQL get
     *  @return array          Formatted data in a row based format
     */
    static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $row = array();

            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
                $column = $columns[$j];

                // Is there a formatter?
                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    if(empty($column['db'])){
                        $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i] );
                    }
                    else{
                        $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(!empty($column['db'])){
                        $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
                    }
                    else{
                        $row[ $column['dt'] ] = "";
                    }
                }
            }

            $out[] = $row;
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Database connection
     *
     * Obtain an PHP PDO connection from a connection details array
     *
     *  @param  array $conn SQL connection details. The array should have
     *    the following properties
     *     * host - host name
     *     * db   - database name
     *     * user - user name
     *     * pass - user password
     *  @return resource PDO connection
     */
    static function db ( $conn )
    {
        if ( is_array( $conn ) ) {
            return self::sql_connect( $conn );
        }

        return $conn;
    }


    /**
     * Paging
     *
     * Construct the LIMIT clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL limit clause
     */
    static function limit ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $limit = '';

        if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
            $limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
        }

        return $limit;
    }


    /**
     * Ordering
     *
     * Construct the ORDER BY clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL order by clause
     */
    static function order ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $order = '';

        if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
            $orderBy = array();
            $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];

                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                        'ASC' :
                        'DESC';

                    $orderBy[] = '`'.$column['db'].'` '.$dir;
                }
            }

            if ( count( $orderBy ) ) {
                $order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
            }
        }

        return $order;
    }


    /**
     * Searching / Filtering
     *
     * Construct the WHERE clause for server-side processing SQL query.
     *
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here performance on large
     * databases would be very poor
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $bindings Array of values for PDO bindings, used in the
     *    sql_exec() function
     *  @return string SQL where clause
     */
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    if(!empty($column['db'])){
                        $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        if ( isset( $request['columns'] ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                $str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
                 $str != '' ) {
                    if(!empty($column['db'])){
                        $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $columnSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';

        if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
            $where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
        }

        if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
            $where = $where === '' ?
                implode(' AND ', $columnSearch) :
                $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $columnSearch);
        }

        if ( $where !== '' ) {
            $where = 'WHERE '.$where;
        }

        return $where;
    }


    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others. The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array|PDO $conn PDO connection resource or connection parameters array
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
                intval( $request['draw'] ) :
                0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }


    /**
     * The difference between this method and the `simple` one, is that you can
     * apply additional `where` conditions to the SQL queries. These can be in
     * one of two forms:
     *
     * * 'Result condition' - This is applied to the result set, but not the
     *   overall paging information query - i.e. it will not effect the number
     *   of records that a user sees they can have access to. This should be
     *   used when you want apply a filtering condition that the user has sent.
     * * 'All condition' - This is applied to all queries that are made and
     *   reduces the number of records that the user can access. This should be
     *   used in conditions where you don't want the user to ever have access to
     *   particular records (for example, restricting by a login id).
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array|PDO $conn PDO connection resource or connection parameters array
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  string $whereResult WHERE condition to apply to the result set
     *  @param  string $whereAll WHERE condition to apply to all queries
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function complex ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );
        $localWhereResult = array();
        $localWhereAll = array();
        $whereAllSql = '';

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        $whereResult = self::_flatten( $whereResult );
        $whereAll = self::_flatten( $whereAll );

        if ( $whereResult ) {
            $where = $where ?
                $where .' AND '.$whereResult :
                'WHERE '.$whereResult;
        }

        if ( $whereAll ) {
            $where = $where ?
                $where .' AND '.$whereAll :
                'WHERE '.$whereAll;

            $whereAllSql = 'WHERE '.$whereAll;
        }

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table` ".
            $whereAllSql
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
                intval( $request['draw'] ) :
                0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }


    /**
     * Connect to the database
     *
     * @param  array $sql_details SQL server connection details array, with the
     *   properties:
     *     * host - host name
     *     * db   - database name
     *     * user - user name
     *     * pass - user password
     * @return resource Database connection handle
     */
    static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
    {
        try {
            $db = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
                $sql_details['user'],
                $sql_details['pass'],
                array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        return $db;
    }


    /**
     * Execute an SQL query on the database
     *
     * @param  resource $db  Database handler
     * @param  array    $bindings Array of PDO binding values from bind() to be
     *   used for safely escaping strings. Note that this can be given as the
     *   SQL query string if no bindings are required.
     * @param  string   $sql SQL query to execute.
     * @return array         Result from the query (all rows)
     */
    static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
    {
        // Argument shifting
        if ( $sql === null ) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
        //echo $sql;

        // Bind parameters
        if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $binding = $bindings[$i];
                $stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
            }
        }

        // Execute
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
        }

        // Return all
        return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
    }


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Internal methods
     */

    /**
     * Throw a fatal error.
     *
     * This writes out an error message in a JSON string which DataTables will
     * see and show to the user in the browser.
     *
     * @param  string $msg Message to send to the client
     */
    static function fatal ( $msg )
    {
        echo json_encode( array( 
            "error" => $msg
        ) );

        exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDO binding key which can be used for escaping variables safely
     * when executing a query with sql_exec()
     *
     * @param  array &$a    Array of bindings
     * @param  *      $val  Value to bind
     * @param  int    $type PDO field type
     * @return string       Bound key to be used in the SQL where this parameter
     *   would be used.
     */
    static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
    {
        $key = ':binding_'.count( $a );

        $a[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'val' => $val,
            'type' => $type
        );

        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Pull a particular property from each assoc. array in a numeric array, 
     * returning and array of the property values from each item.
     *
     *  @param  array  $a    Array to get data from
     *  @param  string $prop Property to read
     *  @return array        Array of property values
     */
    static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            if(empty($a[$i][$prop])){
                continue;
            }
            //removing the $out array index confuses the filter method in doing proper binding,
            //adding it ensures that the array data are mapped correctly
            $out[$i] = $a[$i][$prop];
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Return a string from an array or a string
     *
     * @param  array|string $a Array to join
     * @param  string $join Glue for the concatenation
     * @return string Joined string
     */
    static function _flatten ( $a, $join = ' AND ' )
    {
        if ( ! $a ) {
            return '';
        }
        else if ( $a && is_array($a) ) {
            return implode( $join, $a );
        }
        return $a;
    }
}
```

And the table inisialization / html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#books').DataTable( {
                dom: "<'row'<'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-4'p>>" +
                       "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                       "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'p>>",
                buttons: [
                     {
                         extend: 'collection',
                         text: '<i class="la la-download"></i> Export',
                         autoClose: true,
                         className: 'btn btn-success btn-icon-sm btn-square dropdown-toggle',
                         buttons: [
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>\xa0\xa0  Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>\xa0\xa0  Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>\xa0\xa0  CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>\xa0\xa0  PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>\xa0\xa0  Print', extend: 'print' }
                                  ],
                              fade: true,
                     }
                  ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": 0,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, row ) {
                            "<a class='kt-link kt-font-bold' href='./book/'>"+data+" | "+row[1]+"</a>";
                        },
                    },
                    { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 1 ] }
                ],
                pageLength: 25,
                responsive: true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "index.php?action=ss-books-get"
            } );
} );
    
//    $(document).ready(function(){
//        getBooks();
//    });
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="kt-portlet">
          <div class="kt-portlet__body">
              <?php if(count($autores)>0):?>
              <table class="table table-striped- table-hover" id="books">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>ISBN</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Level</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Copies</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tBody">
                    
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <?php else: ?>
              <?php getAlertMsg("1"); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problems I'm having are:

- Need to mix the Title and Subtitle column into the same one and also get the ID to set the  link.

  "columnDefs": [
  {
  "targets": 0,
  "render": function ( data, type, full, row ) {
  ""+data+" | "+row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5eJY.png)+"";
  },
  },
  { "visible": false,  "targets":  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5eJY.png)  }
  ],

This part works for adding html, but can't mix the data I need...

- Also, I'm getting the level/subject/category from other tables in the DB so, how can I get data from other tables to add the categories list?
- In the "copies" column im calculating the number of copies from 1 book in another table in the BBDD. How could I do that in serverside?

This is my BBDD with the data I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: any ideas? I've been trying but couldn't success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what I needed, I made some changes in the Datatable inizialization script and in the ss-books-get controller.

Datatable Inizialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#books').DataTable( {
          dom: "<'row'<'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-4'p>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'p>>",
          buttons: [
               {
                   extend: 'collection',
                   text: '<i class="la la-download"></i> Export',
                   autoClose: true,
                   className: 'btn btn-success btn-icon-sm btn-square dropdown-toggle',
                   buttons: [
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>\xa0\xa0  Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>\xa0\xa0  Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>\xa0\xa0  CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>\xa0\xa0  PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>\xa0\xa0  Print', extend: 'print' }
                            ],
                        fade: true,
               }
            ],
          "columnDefs": [
              // Use render to mix the title column and the subtitle column and to add the HTML tags. Also generate de buttons grabbing the ID from the id column of the table.
              {
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                      if (row[8] == "") {
                          var title = data;
                      } else {
                          var title = data + ' | ' + row[8];
                      }
                      return '<a class="kt-link kt-font-bold" href="./book/'+row[7]+'" >' + title + '</a>';
                  },
                  "targets": 0
              },
              {
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                      return '<a href="./book/'+row[7]+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="View Book"> <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> </a> <a href="./book/'+row[7]+'#add-copy" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Add Copy"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a> <a href="./book/'+row[7]+'#edit-book" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Edit Book"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> </a> <a href="./index.php?action=book-del&id='+row[7]+'" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md btn-book-del" title="Delete Book"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> </a>';
                  },
                  "targets": 6
              },
              // Then hide the subtitle/id columns (which I won't need to show in frontend)
              { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 7 ] },
              { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 8 ] }
          ],
          pageLength: 25,
          responsive: true,
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "ajax": "index.php?action=ss-books-get"
      } );
} );
```

Controller ss-books-get:

```
<?php

$table = 'library_book';
 
$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    
    array(
        'db'        => 'title',
        'dt'        => 0
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'isbn',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'subject_id',
        'dt'        => 2,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return library::getSubjectByID($d);
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 3,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return library::getLevelsByBookID($d);
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return library::getCategoriesByBookID($d);
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return library::getCountCopiesByBookID($d);
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'type',
        'dt'        => 6
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 7
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'subtitle',
        'dt'        => 8
    ),
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll="hidden = 0 AND type = 1"  )
);
```

I created 4 functions to get the subject, levels, categories and copies by book ID.

Here are the functions:

```
public static function getSubjectByID($id) {
    if ($id == NULL) { $id = 0; } else {}
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_subject";
    $result = $a->select("","",$where="id =".$id);
    if (empty($result)) {
        return '<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--success greysuccess kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill"> N/A </span>';
    } else {
        $result = $result[0];
        return '<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--success kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">'.$result->fields["name"].'</span>';
    }
}
public static function getCategoriesByBookID($id) {
    $final = "";
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_category";
    $categoria= $a->select("","",$where=" hidden = 0");
    $a = "";
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_categoryvsbook";
    $anycat = $a->select("many","","book_id=".$id);
    if (count($anycat)>0) {
        foreach($anycat as $cl) {
            foreach($categoria as $cat) {
                if ($cat->fields["id"] == $cl->fields["category_id"]) {
                    $final .= "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success  kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>".$cat->fields["name"]."</span> ";
                    $a = "";
                } else {

                }
            }
        } 
    } else {
        $final .= "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success greysuccess kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>N/A</span> ";
        $a = "";
    }
    return $final;
}
public static function getLevelsByBookID($id) {
    $final = "";
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_level";
    $categoria= $a->select("","",$where=" hidden = 0");
    $a = "";
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_levelvsbook";
    $anycat= $a->select("many","","book_id=".$id);
    
    if (count($anycat)>0) {
        foreach($anycat as $cl) {
            foreach($categoria as $cat) {
                if ($cat->fields["id"] == $cl->fields["level_id"]) {
                    $final .= "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success  kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>".$cat->fields["name"]."</span> ";
                    $a = "";
                } else {

                }
            }
        } 
    } else {
        $final .= "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success greysuccess kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>N/A</span> ";
        $a = "";
    }
    return $final;
}
public static function getCountCopiesByBookID($id) {
    $result = "";
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "library_copy";
    $ejemplares= $a->select("","",$where=" hidden = 0 AND book_id =".$id);
    
    $count = "0";
    $countb = "0";
    foreach($ejemplares as $ejem) { 
        if ($ejem->fields["status"] == "0") {
            $count++;
        } else {
        }
    }
    $countb = count($ejemplares);
    if ($count>0) { 
        $popcount = "kt-badge--success"; 
    } else { 
        $popcount = "kt-badge--success greysuccessbadge";
    }; 
    $result .= "<span class='kt-badge ".$popcount." kt-badge--dot kt-badge--xl'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; "; 
    $result .= $count . " / " . $countb; 
    $count = "0"; $countb = "0";
    return $result;
}
```

And now it looks exactly the same but the proccesing is faster.